# TCL UTF-8 encoding in ubuntu from http response

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, tcl

Using windows to request http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/idjyusDUGSc?v=2&alt=jsonc returns russian characters. In windows I use:

```
puts "[encoding convertfrom utf-8 $data]"
```

to show the response in cp1252... which works fine.

I shouldn't have to convert while using ubuntu because its utf-8 system encoding... or so I thought, but it will not return correctly.  Using:

```
package require http
set token [http::geturl http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/idjyusDUGSc?v=2&alt=jsonc]
set data [http::data $token]
puts $data
```

returns an incorrect encoding

Comment: I've tried a foreach statement with convertto and convertfrom that looped through every [encoding names]. help! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`http::meta $token` says that the content is already in utf-8.
If you `http::geturl` directly into file channel, the file will be in utf-8:

```
package require http
set out [open response.txt w]
http::geturl http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/idjyusDUGSc?v=2&alt=jsonc -channel $out
close $out
```

Tested on Windows XP.

Comment: http responded with application/json; charset=UTF-8 but thats not the problem. Ubuntu is default charset is UTF-8 as well so it shouldn't have an issue displaying but it still doesn't display correctly. Anything in Russian displays as a bunch of A's. Curl on ubuntu show the same issue.

Comment: ÐÐ¾ Ð²Ð¾Ð¿ÑÐ¾ÑÐ°Ð¼ Ð»Ð¸ÑÐµÐ½Ð·Ð¸ÑÐ¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ Ð¸ ÑÐ¾ÑÑÑÐ´Ð½Ð¸ÑÐµÑÑÐ²Ð°, Ð¿Ð¾Ð¶Ð°Ð»ÑÐ¹ÑÑÐ° Ð¾Ð±ÑÐ°ÑÐ°Ð¹ÑÐµÑÑ Ðº Ð°Ð²ÑÐ¾ÑÑ: https://vk.com/id80383812 Ð

Comment: cat response.txt
80C
{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"id":"idjyusDUGSc","uploaded":"2014-07-12T16:10:43.000Z","updated":"2014-07-21T21:07:17.000Z","uploader":"BtcbA_dfFhW9zsBdQthEAw","category":"Entertainment","title":"A sudden hail storm in Russia (Novosibirsk) 12.07.2014 | ÐÐ½ÐµÐ·Ð°Ð¿Ð½ÑÐ¹ ÑÑÐ°Ð³Ð°Ð½ Ð² Ð
0

Comment: Try also `set ::http::defaultCharset utf-8` before `http::geturl`. Documentation says that if none was specified, this defaults to the RFC standard iso8859-1.

Comment: I am not sure about Ubuntu. If curl and cat do the same, can there be any settings to check in terminal emulator? What encoding the file is in if you open it in Gedit, Geany or GVim?

Comment: Sorry I never responded, I attached to a different email for faster verification. I ended up just regsub'ing all the unknown charecters to work around. Was taking to long. Thanks.